# MS access query optimizing

Tags: ms-access

I got issue with access after new computer.That new computer have less GHz in single core that older and access using only one core.

I find out most of load takes one query that counts all balances and can not think how to count all balances some another way so computer would not take 4 sec to calculate all data eaxh time this query in use.
Code that I use now for query

```
PARAMETERS KodMater Text ( 255 );
SELECT 
  DISTINCTROW Mater.NumberMat
   , IIf(IsNull([Query Sum Likuc]!SumOfKiekPajam),0,[Query Sum Likuc]!SumOfKiekPajam)
  +IIf(IsNull([Query sum Pajam]!SumOfKiekPajam),0,[Query sum Pajam]!SumOfKiekPajam)
  -IIf(IsNull([Query Sum Nuras]!SumOfKiekNuras),0,[Query Sum Nuras]!SumOfKiekNuras)
  -IIf(IsNull([Query Sum Pard]!SumOfKiekNuras),0,[Query Sum Pard]!SumOfKiekNuras)
  -IIf(IsNull([Query Sum PardV]!SumOfKiekNuras),0,[Query Sum PardV]!SumOfKiekNuras
  ) AS Expr1
FROM 
  ((((Mater 
      LEFT JOIN [Query Sum Likuc] ON Mater.NumberMat = [Query Sum Likuc].NumberMat) 
      LEFT JOIN [Query sum Pajam] ON Mater.NumberMat = [Query sum Pajam].MaterID) 
      LEFT JOIN [Query Sum Pard] ON Mater.NumberMat = [Query Sum Pard].MaterID) 
      LEFT JOIN [Query Sum Nuras] ON Mater.NumberMat = [Query Sum Nuras].MaterID) 
      LEFT JOIN [Query Sum PardV] ON Mater.NumberMat = [Query Sum PardV].MaterID
WHERE (((Mater.NumberMat) Like [KodMater]));
```

Code that I use rezult

[image: query rezult]

Query data without merge

[image: Data of query without merge]

Comment: Data in displayed tables are not associated. Would be nice to see same NumberMat values. Is Sandel2 example of raw data in table?

Comment: Why the mysql tag?